# Best RAID config for Data Backup NAS?

Tags: backup, raid, network-attached-storage, synology

Currently looking in to a NAS backup solution which will primarily be used for storing images of a few employees laptops and also storing some internal data. Most likely going to go with the Synology DiskStation DS415+ 4 Bay Enclosure and some WD Red drives as they seem to be reliable and trusted!!

Now my big problem is deciding on what RAID to use.. I believe RAID 6 is the more reliable and can withstand any 2 drives dying? We have 4 bays and would like half of the drives to be used for storage. We will most likely be writing small amounts of data daily though so the performance could be an issue with RAID 6 as opposed to RAID 10.

So my question is...

- What RAID is best for data recovery?
- Am I able to just pull a drive out with all the data on for an easy off-site backup? Would obviously replace this with a new fresh drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> What RAID is best for data recovery?
> ```

That depends on your use case. It depends whether you want more redundancy, more storage capacity or more performance. See [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/raid-levels-tutorial/) overview for more information about the specific levels.

> ```
> Am I able to just pull a drive out with all the data on for an easy off-site backup? Would obviously replace this with a new fresh drive.
> ```

This depends on the RAID level.

Comment: Thanks for that! It seems like RAID 1 may well be the best solution for us.

Comment: Not sure why you have accepted an answer which doesn't really answer the question or even mention RAID 1 that you have chosen in your comment!

Comment: He provided something useful to help me come to that conclusion, I was more after hearing suggestions than getting an 'answer' as everyone has different ways of deciding what is best for them.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only 4 slots, then just use raid 6. With only a few employee, I don't think you need to worry about performance.

You can't just pull out the drives and expect it would work elsewhere. It will most likely work if you have purchase the same NAS box and put the hard drive in.

But I would just buy a second NAS box and then have them in sync.